# Facebook share. Change "say something more about this", multiple buttons on the same page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-share

I know I can use `ob:description` meta tag to change what is displayed by default in "say something more about this" when user clicks Facebook share button.

However, I am adding multiple share buttons dynamically to my page (it's SPA app), each of them refers to different URL, however, how can I assign different "say something about this" for each of them, if I can add meta tag only once?

Comment: You can't. You need a unique url for each thing you share

Comment: I have a list of articles. Each of them is unique. But they are all listed in one page, therefore I want a lot of share buttons. How can I have different "say something more.." for each of these buttons? They are added dynamically and they are all on the same page.

Comment: I tried to change the meta tag with jquery, but looks like FB is not aware of that and uses value that was the originally. I need an alternative for those crappy meta tags..

Comment: Facebooks crawler don't run Javascript. So when we curl you later we have no idea what you changed them too for the user

Comment: Well, twitter allows data-text attribute for each of tweet buttons. It works perfectly. Does Facebook offer something similar? https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet

Comment: You can't in my first post meant that you can't. You should share a unique link because the user when they click on that item is expecting to get sent to that item. But just add ?id=number in the url and then have it scroll to the right item

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to change is the User message, right? ("Say something about this..."). Which is not possible at all in the Share Dialog, and it would not be allowed anyway according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> 2.3: Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message
>   parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>   person can edit or remove the content before sharing.